# How to get all database names in one linked server?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

We have created one linked server with name

'server_linked_090215'

How do we get all database names which this linked server can access?

Comment: I think you to list out all the databases in the linked server. Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806854/how-to-determine-if-database-exists-on-linked-server

Comment: Any updates SQL folk?

Answer (score 1):

you can use to get all DBs in SQL Server instance

```
SELECT name
FROM master..sysdatabases
```

for linked servers:

```
select * from server_linked_090215.master.sys.databases
```

Comment: This will give all databases under same server. I want to know how many databases and which databases this linked server can access?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
select * from server_linked_090215.master.sys.databases
```

Comment: This will give all databases under same server as the Master database will be same for the the same server. I want to know how many databases and which databases this linked server can access?