# selecting specific columns from different tables and different database

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have 3 Database

```
  - ECPNWEB
  - ECPNDB
  - ECPNPOS
```

and also 3 tables

```
  - account -> ECPNWEB
  - branch -> ECPNDB
  - terminal -> ECPNPOS
```

and the tables having multiple columns

```
  - account (accntid,managedby,account,first,last,....)
  - branch(branch_code,company_code,name,distributor,cutoff,....)
  - terminal(retail,brand,model,serial,status,....)
```

All I want to do is to get the specific column.,
my desired output is:

```
 managedby for table account and ECPNWEB database
 name for table branch and ECPNDB database
 model for table terminal and ECPNPOS database..
```

Like this

```
 |managedby|name|model
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: it it not too clear to me how you want to get the data back.
Option 1 SELECT managedby FROM account UNION SELECT name from Branch
OR
Oprion 2 SELECT account.ManagedBy, Branch.Name FROM Account, Name.

Is there a common link between the tables?

Comment: 3 databases on 3 servers or on 1 server?

Comment: 1. Are these databases in the same instance? 2. How are these tables related to each other?

Comment: They are not related to each other @Kaf all i want is to view this three columns with different tables,different databases,and different server..thanks..sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @ErikE 3 databases in 3 servers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sp_addlinkedserver()` is what you need
2. `exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = '*server_name*'` //---replace *server_name* with yours
3. it will look like this: e.g. `select * from [server].[database].[schema].[table]`
4. Check out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

I'm not about it but try this and tell me what is the o/p. For example you can try this way

```
SELECT firstdb.*, seconddb.*
FROM Server1.Database1.dbo.myTable AS firstdb
INNER JOIN Server2.Database2.dbo.myTable AS seconddb
   ON firstdb.id = seconddb.id
```

EDIT2: try this,not sure this will give u desired result, not tested... replace *column_name* with yours

```
SELECT account.managedby, branch.name, terminal.model FROM ECPNWEB.dbo.account, ECPNDB.dbo.branch, ECPNPOS.dbo.terminal AS a INNER JOIN account ON account.(column_name)=branch.(column_name)  INNER JOIN terminal ON account.(column_name)=terminal.(column_name)
```

Comment: Ive added the Linked server,Now the problem is I dont know query to get the output .. please help.. @Vinayak

Comment: @KristianHernanC.Manuel can you check the edit? my machine not having sql server or any db engine. Can you edit your post and tell what query you are running?

Comment: @Its working but not related to the topic..the desired output is not there..please help..thanks

Comment: @KristianHernanC.Manuel ok give me a min

Comment: @KristianHernanC.Manuel check EDIT 2. Not sure about it.

Comment: what's about common attribute? @Vinayak

Comment: damn my bad ... it must be column_name *where's my mind* doh!

Comment: Add info about DTC please!