# SQL: Executing a query to dynamic remote server

Tags: sql

I want to be able to execute remote queries based on the results of a local query.

For instance:

```
DECLARE @REMOTESERVER VARCHAR(10)

Select TOP 1 @REMOTESERVER = RemoteServer from TABLE
```

--Execute the next query on a remote server from the value I retrieved above

```
Select * from tblCustomers
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What RDBMS are you using?  Some will not support a pure sql way of doing this.  Others, like SQL Server, might support this scenario.  Is the remote server accessible via a linked server that you can access.  You could then use dynamic sql to create your sql string.  Something like this should work in SQL Server:

```
SET @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @RemoteServer + '].dbname.schema.tblCustomers'
EXEC @Sql
```

Here is a post about linked servers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4091984/1073631

Comment: Yes, that worked thanks!  The only thing I had to do differently was wrap the exec variable as such:
EXEC(@Sql)

Thanks!