# Copy one table from a server to another server using query MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

How can I copy a table to another server. It's a linked server. I used this code, but it is not working.

```
INSERT INTO [E-SVR].enrollmentCollege.CDDT_MSTR (position_id)
SELECT position_id FROM LETRAN.enrollmentCollege.CDDT_MSTR
```

Thank you.

Comment: Elaborate on "it is not working"? Are you linking from to a remote SQL server?

Comment: Take a look at this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091960/sql-server-linked-server-example-query

Comment: I get this error. Could not find server 'LETRAN' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers. How can I do that?

Comment: I under the impression... from your post that the linked server has already been created. Is that not correct?

Comment: I thought it was already linked, but when I executed your given codes, I get that error so I assume it is not yet linked.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
INSERT INTO [E-SVR].[enrollmentCollege].[dbo].CDDT_MSTR (position_id)
SELECT position_id FROM [LETRAN].[enrollmentCollege].[dbo].CDDT_MSTR
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think "LETRAN" server name is incorrect because I get this error.. "Could not find server 'LETRAN' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
"

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

INSERT INTO enrollmentCollege..CDDT_MSTR (position_id) SELECT position_id FROM LETRAN.enrollmentCollege..CDDT_MSTR

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a 4-part name for a table (which you have to so to use a linked server as part of the name), you need to specify the schema (the 3rd part) as well:

```
INSERT INTO [E-SVR].enrollmentCollege.dbo.CDDT_MSTR (position_id)
SELECT position_id FROM LETRAN.enrollmentCollege.dbo.CDDT_MSTR
```

If you want to use the default schema, you can leave the schema part empty:

```
INSERT INTO [E-SVR].enrollmentCollege..CDDT_MSTR (position_id)
SELECT position_id FROM LETRAN.enrollmentCollege..CDDT_MSTR
```

Comment: I execute "select * from sys.servers" and get the server name "LETRAN"
But, i still get this error.. "Could not find server 'LETRAN' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
"

Comment: OK, have you linked this server?

Comment: I think not yet, I get this error. Could not find server 'LETRAN' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.