# SQL Server 2016 Fails Cryptically (Error #7303) on Link to MySQL, But Access 2016 Succeeds with Same System DSN

Tags: mysql, sql-server, odbc, msdasql

I am going around in crop circles, trying to set up a linked server (from SQL Server 2016 to MySQL).

Here is the basic procedure that I used:  [Create a Linked Server to MySQL from SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4577/create-a-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/).  Upon clicking OK to create the new linked server, I received the following SSMS 2016 spasm, Error #7303:

```
The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?

Additional information:
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL".
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)
```

[image: Error 7303:]

I tried variations that included a Provider String and Catalog (same error):

[image: Linked-Server Dialog:]

I have tried the latest MySQL ODBC ANSI/Unicode drivers (5.03.07.00), set up via System DSNs in both the 32- and 64-bit versions of the ODBC Data Source Administrator.

Now, I suspect that something screwy is going on with MS SQL Server and/or its OLE-DB Provider (MSDASQL), because:

1. All tests of the System DSNs within the ODBC Data Source
   Administrator are successful.
2. Crippled Access 2016 is able to link (via the aforementioned Unicode System
   DSN) to MySQL just fine, with minimal effort, listing all databases
   and tables.

What is the magic that SQL Server 2016 needs to make the linked-server dialog not result in the above error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things --

1. *Product Name* should be **`MSDASQL`**.
2. Leave *Provider String* and *Catalog* blank (these are typically taken care of by your DSN definition).

That should do it...

Comment: Thanks for the try:  Your clean-and-simple approach looks like it should work, but I got the same Error 7303, verbatim (the error dialog looks exactly like the one above).

Comment: Likely other candidates... Make sure that [both 32-bit *and* 64-bit ODBC DSNs (same name) are configured; and that both 32-bit *and* 64-bit MSDASQL are present](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/MsSqlOn64bitWin). Permissions can also lead to this error — possibly re-install things "as Administrator" and/or check the user as which SQL Server is running.

Comment: Excellent, @TallTed:  Your recommendations made me go back and re-install (the seemingly present) drivers.  That did it!

A flipped bit must have caused the error, because I merely retraced my steps, naming everything the same.  After that, I entered things per the "New Linked Server" dialog above, but left out, as recommended, the Provider String and Catalog.  Presto!  No error after clicking the dialog's OK button.

Comment: Then, I was able to do a SELECT, but only via OPENQUERY:  

`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'select * from company.employees')`

returned all records.

Comment: To use dot notation with a simple SELECT, use brackets and an EXTRA dot, as follows (database=company, table=employees):  `SELECT * FROM [MYSQL]...[company.employees]
`
See Pawel's answer, here:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968343/select-from-mysql-linked-server-using-sql-server-without-openquery)