# Connecting to multiple servers (Sql server)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I use windowform to create a report form but the data is for 4 different servers(SQL server). How can I organize data for the simplest query.
Thanks.

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: Are your servers using a single data model or different for each?

Comment: Please explain the situation correctly, by organizing you mean running the query on all server at once? Or are we talking about accessing data from each server and then manipulating in in code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you?
[SQL Server Linked Server Example Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091960/sql-server-linked-server-example-query)

example:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(Linked_Server_Name , 'select * from Table')
```