# Query a database from a different database

Tags: sql

Hi I am new to sql and currently developing a report in ssrs.  I have a report I built using tables from a database (db 1) but also need information from a different dabatase (db 2), is there a way for me to select information  in db 2 from db 1 where I have built my report but need 2 columns from db 2?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Linked Server Example Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091960/sql-server-linked-server-example-query)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server offers something called [Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine) to accomplish this.

You start off by issuing a command to set up the linked server:

```
USE [master]  
GO  
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver   
    @server = N'Server2EnteredTheGame',   
    @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;  
GO
```

And the  set things up to use the domain account of the local server:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin   
    @rmtsrvname = N'Server2EnteredTheGame',   
    @locallogin = NULL ,   
    @useself = N'True' ;  
GO
```

You can then issue queries against the linked server:

```
SELECT name FROM [Server2EnteredTheGame].MyDatabase.MySchema.MyTable;  
GO
```

However, couldn't you just add a second datasource to the report, and go at it that way?