# Connection string for Linked Servers Database

Tags: sql-server

I have created a "Link Server" in my SQL server 2012. Now I want to get data from a table which is under a "Link Server".
So for that, what will be the connection string to connect with a database under "Link Server"?

In the console application I have tried this.

```
<add key="smartdb" value="Data Source=192.168.1.141; Initial Catalog=mydb;User Id=sa;Password=sa123" />
```

But it's not working. I don't know where to set the database name, which is under "Linked server".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4091984/2993606

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 or you can use 4 part names (Server.Database.Schema.Table) where the server name is the name of the linked server.

Comment: "It's not working" doesn't mean anything. Do you have an error message? There are two servers here. The one you are linking _to_ (is defined in the linked server definition) and the one the you are linking from (the one where you define the linked server)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a four-part query to connect to your linked server:

```
<server-name>.<database-name>.<schema-name>.<table-name>
```

So in your connection string change the data source.

Comment: Yes. First i need a connection. So in connection string how to set database name.

Comment: You said, that you've created the linked server already... you can specify the initial catalog there, or you can set up the user on the remote server to have the desired database as default. You can specify the database in the query (using 3 or 4 part names). `OPENQUERY` has no 'database' parameter, and when you are using 4 part names, that name contains the database name already. So what exactly you have done and working and what is the exact problem?

Comment: @MarufAhammedJuwel First connect to your parent sql server where you have the linked sql server created and from there you run your queries as open queries and get the data.
Open query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <add name="sqlConnection" connectionString="your connection string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by putting initial catalog "master". Then I can query Like:

```
<add key="smartdb" value="Data Source=192.168.1.141; Initial Catalog=master;User Id=sa;Password=sa123" />
```

and query

```
select * from MYLINK.SPL.dbo.Departments
```

Now I can get result expected.