# How can I join two tables from two different connections or instances in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, join, database-connection, instance

How to join two tables from different connections / instances in SQL Server?

Something like this :

```
select * 
from [connection1].[database].[table] c1
join [connection2].[database].[table] c2 on c1.id = c2.id
```

Comment: Please find the format [`<server>.<database>.<schema>.<table>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4091984/2451726)

Comment: check out making linked servers

Comment: hi guys. I found the solution and its worked for me :                       
 http://txt.do/dzpcu