# Creating a SQL server view from multiple DB engines?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, view, ssis

I have a SQL server DB, a Oracle DB, a MySQL DB. I have a way to join the tables from each DB. How would be the best way to create this view? I have just started SSIS project that pulls the tables from the DBs and creates the view I want, but is there a way to grab the data from each engine in the view in real-time\dynamic?

Comment: I'd guess step one would be to put them all on a single database server.

Comment: Load the data from other Db's to one db and create the view. If you use linked server it has other issues until unless data is very small.

Comment: @Ed that's possible but that would be a massive project.

Comment: @Roshan I have the Oracle linked to the MSSQL already. I'll look at linking the MySQL tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Having thought about it a bit more, you could probably do it with an SQL proxy server. I've not looked into the capabilities of SQL proxy servers; you would need one that could connect to all of the servers that couldn't already talk with each other.

Comment: @Roshan I tried OpenQuery 2 years ago maybe this time I'll have better luck with it... maybe.

Comment: You asked "best" - the best way is not to cross instance boundaries in a select query, especially in a heterogeneous environment. Linked servers can be very fragile - especially when dealing with many rows. But your description is confusing. A SSIS project would typically be used to move/copy data between databases, so it isn't clear what your SSIS project does nor what your real goal is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thr best way to do that is to create a linked server for each instance (Oracle, MySQL) on sql server without the need to copy data.

And then you can create a view that join the tables between instances.

For more information, you can follow these articles:

- [Create Linked Servers (SQL Server Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Create a linked server to MySQL from SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4577/create-a-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/)
- [Creating a SQL Server 2014 Linked Server for an Oracle 11g Database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4396/creating-a-sql-server-2014-linked-server-for-an-oracle-11g-database/)
- [SQL Server Linked Server Example Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091960/sql-server-linked-server-example-query)