# how can i select a table from linked server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm tring to run this SQL query :

```sql
select * from openquery(CUIC,'select * from [informix].[agentcalldetailsnapshot]')
```

I expect a selected table but I have this error message as a result:

`Msg 7321, Niveau 16, État 2, Ligne 1
An error occurred while preparing the query "select * from [informix].[agentcalldetailsnapshot]" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CUIC".`

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: If it's a linked server, why not use 4 part naming? `SELECT * FROM [Server].[Database].[Schema].[Table];`? Also, in your query, you appear to be missing the name of the database.

Comment: thx for your help                                                                                                                                I heve tried :select * from openquery(CUIC,'select * from [CUIC].[default].[informix].[agentcalldetailsnapshot]') but it's always the same error

Comment: That isn't what I said to do, I don't have `OPENQUERY` in the above.

Comment: possible duplicate of:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091960/sql-server-linked-server-example-query

Comment: it still the same error message