# Want to compare 4 different columns with the result of CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, common-table-expression

I have created a CTE (common table Expression) as follows:

```
DECLARE @N VARCHAR(100)

WITH CAT_NAM AS (    
    SELECT ID, NAME
    FROM TABLE1    
    WHERE YEAR(DATE) = YEAR(GETDATE())    
)    
SELECT @N = STUFF((
    SELECT ','''+ NAME+''''    
    FROM CAT_NAM    
    WHERE ID IN (20,23,25,30,37)   
    FOR XML PATH ('')    
),1,1,'')
```

The result of above CTE is 'A','B','C','D','F'

Now I need to check 4 different columns CAT_NAM_1,CAT_NAM_2,CAT_NAM_3,CAT_NAM_4 in the result of CTE and form it as one column like follow:

```
Select 
case when CAT_NAM_1 in (@N) then CAT_NAM_1
     when CAT_NAM_2 in (@N) then CAT_NAM_2
     when CAT_NAM_3 in (@N) then CAT_NAM_3
     when CAT_NAM_4 in (@N) then CAT_NAM_4
end as CAT
from table2
```

When I'm trying to do the above getting error please help me to do.
If my approach is wrong help me with right one.

Comment: Do not combine separate values into one CSV, join as-is, then group if needed.

Comment: `in (@N)` isn't doing what you think it does. It would be equivalent to `= @n`.

Comment: What if two columns match then what should the result be?

Comment: No 2 columns will have matching values for one cat_ID. I will select cat_ID also in the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but if I understand the following script shows one possible technique. I have created some table variables to mimic the data you presented and then wrote a `SELECT` statement to do what I think you asked (but I am not sure).

```sql
DECLARE @TABLE1 AS TABLE (
    ID INT NOT NULL, 
    [NAME] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    [DATE] DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @TABLE1(ID,[NAME],[DATE])
VALUES (20, 'A', '2021-01-01'), (23, 'B', '2021-02-01'),
(25, 'C', '2021-03-01'),(30, 'D', '2021-04-01'),
(37, 'E', '2021-05-01'),(40, 'F', '2021-06-01');

DECLARE @TABLE2 AS TABLE (
    ID INT NOT NULL, 
    CAT_NAM_1 VARCHAR(10) NULL, 
    CAT_NAM_2 VARCHAR(10) NULL, 
    CAT_NAM_3 VARCHAR(10) NULL, 
    CAT_NAM_4 VARCHAR(10) NULL
);

INSERT INTO @TABLE2(ID,CAT_NAM_1,CAT_NAM_2,CAT_NAM_3,CAT_NAM_4)
VALUES (1,'A',NULL,NULL,NULL),(2,NULL,'B',NULL,NULL);

;WITH CAT_NAM AS (
    SELECT ID, [NAME]
    FROM @TABLE1 
    WHERE YEAR([DATE]) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
    AND ID IN (20,23,25,30,37,40)
)
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CAT_NAM WHERE CAT_NAM.[NAME] = CAT_NAM_1) THEN CAT_NAM_1 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CAT_NAM WHERE CAT_NAM.[NAME] = CAT_NAM_2) THEN CAT_NAM_2
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CAT_NAM WHERE CAT_NAM.[NAME] = CAT_NAM_3) THEN CAT_NAM_3
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CAT_NAM WHERE CAT_NAM.[NAME] = CAT_NAM_4) THEN CAT_NAM_4 
    ELSE '?' -- not sure what you want if there is no match
END AS CAT
FROM @TABLE2;
```

Comment: yes, the above mentioned is what I wanted. Please let me know, if the table1 and table2 are in two different servers, then how to get the above solution. Thanks.

Comment: @AshDil if the data is on two different servers, then you could consider a linked server from one server to another and then use it that way as shown in the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091960/sql-server-linked-server-example-query/4091984 . You can research linked servers to see if that would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a bit of set-based logic for this

```sql
SELECT
    ct.NAME
FROM table2 t2
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT v.NAME
      FROM (VALUES
        (t2.CAT_NAM_1),
        (t2.CAT_NAM_2),
        (t2.CAT_NAM_3),
        (t2.CAT_NAM_4)
      ) v(NAME)
    INTERSECT
    SELECT ct.NAM
      FROM CAT_NAM ct
      WHERE ct.ID IN (20,23,25,30,37)
) ct;
```

Comment: Hi I will try out your approach. Thanks.