# How to access LinkedServer on another database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to know how to access LinkedServer of databaseA from databaseB in SQL Server.

I need to know sample code. Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for an option to achieve this. As of know I couldn't find any.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64332431/4892466

Comment: LinkedServer already created on databaseA, and databaseB wants to connect to databaseA and than access databaseA's LinkedServer.. this is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

If the servers are already linked, are both running SQL Server (you're not linking to a different kind of database completely), and you are connected to `databaseB` with a login having appropriate permissions, here is an example:

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM ServerName.databaseA.schema.Table alias
WHERE alias.Column = 'SomeValue'
```

Note you need to use all four parts of the name (server, database, schema, object), and therefore you will definitely want to use a table alias. The schema is practically almost always `dbo`, and can often be elided with just an extra `.` ( `FROM ServerName.databaseA..Table`).

But as long as you get the name right, you can use items in `databaseA` as if they were there in B, including for JOINs and similar. However, performance can be poor, because the server for `databaseB` must put together an execution plan without knowing anything about indexes or statics from `databaseA`.

If the `databaseA` is something other than SQL Server, you will need to use [`OPENQUERY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Like the first option, `OPENQUERY()` results can be given an alias and then used with JOIN, APPLY, subquery, etc, and the same warning about performance applies.